# Transparency Issue I've never seen [Blender Render]

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

So I'm using a mesh with a blushing texture that I hide in my character's head to create a blushing face with a shape key. I've done this before with no problem. This time I've run into a problem I've never seen. Parts of the blush mesh seem to cause any mesh behind it to become transparent when I turn on alpha settings, as seen below:
[image]

The only difference between this time and last is that I'm using a single texture for both the face mesh and the blushing mesh. Could that be causing the issue?

Here is the texture:
[image]

Here are my transparency settings:

[image][image][image]

Comment: I'm flat chat at present, but on the face of it you appear to be seeing the Viewport/OpenGL masking effect, in that a 'younger' & semmi-transparent object is masking out an 'older' object.  See here for the mechanics of this. (text under the 1st image)  I don't fully understand what it is you're doing here, but if you've got two different material slots for the same object, make sure the semmi-transparent one is at the bottom of the slots list. (use the little triangles to step them up and down in the list)  Any slot below the transparent one will be rendered invisible when the 2 are together.

Comment: Link for the above - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/how-to-put-a-mask-into-3d-space/117941#117941